# Why my newly created postgres RDS has constant write IOPS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, postgresql-12

Why my newly created postgres RDS has constant read/write IOPS plus CPU utilization? I didn't use the rds in any of my app, nor does it open to public network.

[image]

And I am just using the default param group.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Impossible to say on a hosted database, but since the spikes are occurring regularly, I'd guess it is the monitoring system and checkpoint activity.

To find out more, set `log_min_duration_statement = 0` and `log_checkpoints = on` and examine the log.